# Business formalities

Tags: forms-of-address

I addressed a customer as Dear “X” and replied to me by using only my first name Dimitris. Do I need to reply the same or to keep the expression Dear “X”?

Comment: Impossible to say without being a party to the interchange.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is a question about relationships, not about language per se; what the proper response would be depends a great deal on your relationship with the customer, your cultural backgrounds, the context of the exchange, and so on. Even controlling for broader trends, some customers prefer to maintain distance and others prefer to remove it; there is no single right or wrong answer.

Comment: This is out of the scope of this question, but it would be interesting to discuss the appropriateness of emoji usage in formal communication. I think it would follow roughly the same rule as my answer below, wherein the client/boss/whoever has authority in the exchange gets to set the terms of the communication but *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in the business environment if someone emails

> Dear Mr. Hubbard,
>
> Your order is ready to ship. Thank you for your business.
>
> Best wishes,
>
> Dimitris [Smith]
>
> Customer Service

And I reply

> Thank you, Dimitris!
>
> Best wishes,
>
> Mark

Then it is acceptable to reply using my first name, as I have set a precedent by using my own.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how formal you feel you need to keep the communication, as well as who the full audience of the conversation is. In certain workplaces, it wouldn't be unusual for a handful of additional people to be included on email chains like this one. In that case, I would generally air on the side of formality and stick to

> Mr. X

or

> Dear Mr. X

for my greetings.

If the conversation is in the context of an ongoing relationship, as in a one-on-one conversation with a coworker/client/boss, I would let them set the terms for formality. If they reply with your first name, respond with your first name.

You:

> Dear Mr. X,

Client:

> Morning Jim,

You:

> Morning Barb,

As a general rule of thumb, however, you will never be called out or penalized for being too formal in a workplace environment. Even if you are, in a place truly committed to a lack of formality, it would be hard to imagine it actually upsetting anyone, and then you would have your answer clearly from an authority.